# C++ append vector into another vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to append one vector to another vector, both vectors being same in "dimension".

```
int main()
{
std::vector<int> v1={1,2,3,4,5},v2={10,11,12};
//v1.push_back(v2)?
//v1 and v2 have same dimensions

}
```

Without creating loops and pushing back individual element, is there any way to achieve similar to this python statements?

```
v1=[1,2,3,4,5]
v2=[10,11,12]
v1.extend(v2)
print(v1)
```

gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12]`

Comment: Without iterators? Why that restriction? They are exactly the tool for stuff like this.

Comment: is std::copy allowed.. It will be one line but it will need to use iterators

Comment: OK. Using iterators

Comment: Then it's an easy one-liner indeed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());`